# Replace all hyperlinks in a string using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, replace

I want a regular expression for VB.NET to remove all hyperlinks in a string, including protocols https and http, full document name, subdomains,  querystring parameters, so all links like:

- http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com/
- https://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com/page.html?t=7
- http://example.com?q=test&sort=1
- www.example.com
- etc

Here's the string I'm working with in which all links need to be removed:

```
Dim description As String

description = "Deep purples blanket / wrap. It is gorgeous" & _
"in newborn photography. " & _
"layer" & _
"beneath the baby.....the possibilities are endless!" & _
"You will get this prop! " & _
"Gorgeous images using Lavender as a basket filler " & _
"Photo by Benbrook, TX" & _
"Imaging, Ontario" & _
"http://www.photo.com?t=3" & _
" www.photo.com" & _
" http://photo.com" & _
" https://photo.com" & _
" http://www.photo.nl?t=1&url=5" & _
"Photography Cameron, NC" & _
"Thank you so much ladies!!" & _
"The flower halos has beautiful items!" & _
"http://www.enchanting.etsy.com" & _
"LIKE me on FACEBOOK for coupon codes, and to see my full product line!" & _
"http://www.facebook.com/byme"
```

What I have now:

```
description = Regex.Replace(description, _
                    "((http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-‌​zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*)", "")
```

It replaces most links, but not links without protocol, like `www.example.com`

How I alter my expression to include these links?

Comment: Downvote reason: with over 1,600 reputation you should know [ask]. Hint: Show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the string with `Split()` and then check each element. If it can be parsed as an absolute Uri, discard it from the array, and then re-build the string:

```
Dim urlStr As String
Dim resultUri As Uri
urlStr = "Beautiful images using Lavender, see https://www.foo.com" & vbCrLf & _
    "Plent of links http://www.foo.com/page.html?t=7 Oshawa, Ontario" & vbCrLf & _
    "http://www.example.com" & vbCrLf & "Photography, NC"

Dim resNoURL = String.Join(" ", urlStr.Split().Select(Function(m As String)
                      If Uri.TryCreate(m, UriKind.Absolute, resultUri) = False Then
                          Return m
                      End If
                      End Function).ToList())
```

Result:

[image]

Alternatively, check if `m` starts with `http://` or `https://`. You can even use a regex check:

```
Dim rx As Regex = New Regex("(?i)^(?:https?|ftps?)://")
```

And then in the callback:

```
If rx.IsMatch(m) = False Then
    Return m
End If
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a [sample code](http://ideone.com/kHC58y) removing the URLs from the string:

```
Dim urlStr As String
urlStr = "YOUR STRING"
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("(?:(http|https|ftp)://|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9._?,'/\\+&%$#=~-])*")
Console.WriteLine(MyRegex.Replace(urlStr, ""))
```

Comment: According to here it should not be required to split the string first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6811780/769449
I've updated my question with the regex I'm using now, but I'm now missing one part where the link has no protocol in it...can you help?

Comment: Do you want to also detect links like `www.something.com` with the regex you have? Try `((?:(http|https|ftp)://|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-‌​zA-Z0-9._?,'/\\+&%$#=~-])*)`. It is the same regex, I just added www and removed unnecessary escaping.

Comment: Yes, I want to detect those links too, but your regular expression does not replace the links in my samle string, which I just added...

Comment: Look at [this demo, no URLs remain after the replacement](http://ideone.com/kHC58y).